# Find if a number is within Fibonacci range

Tags: c#, numbers, position, range, fibonacci

I have printed some Fibonacci numbers. Now I want to see if a number / which I enter / is within that range and if it is, to show it's position.
This is what I have so far:

```
using System;

namespace SomeFibonacciPrimes
{
    class SomeFibonacciPrimes
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int first = 0;
            int second = 1;
            int third = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                third = second;
                second = first + second;
                first = third;
                Console.WriteLine(second);                      
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to find if it's in Fibonacci      range:");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (number == second)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is within the Fibonacci range.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is NOT within the Fibonacci range");
            }
       }
   }
}
```

I can't understand why the If statement prints the else result if I enter a number that I SEE in the range?!
I think that after I manage to make the If statement to work, the position is the "i" in the for statement?

Comment: What do you enter for example? You are aware you are comparing your `number` with `second`, right? I mean, not for any range.

Comment: You aren't storing the numbers, therefore `second` will be the last number in the range IE the last Fibonacci number under 50. So you will always get the else statement for any number other than that number.

Comment: After I print the range I pick for example the number 89 / it is in the range / and the If statement prints me the "else" result?! I think that the '==' operator looks in the entire range of second, is it not?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use either an `array of integer` or `List of integer` to solve this: as like the following:

```
            int first = 0;
            int second = 1;
            int third = 1;
            List<int> fibnoList= new List<int>();                  
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                fibnoList.Add(second);  
                Console.WriteLine(second); //To print the series  
                third = second;
                second = first + second;
                first = third;                                    
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to find if it's in Fibonacci      range:");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (fibnoList.Contains(number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is within the Fibonacci range.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is NOT within the Fibonacci range");
            }
```

Comment: It wasn't from me?!
"The type or namespace name "List" could not be found"? Why?!

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: IT WORKED!!! :D But now it doesn't print the Fibonacci numbers within the range. Never mind that I'll make it work! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using looping, maybe you can consider this

```
using System;

namespace SomeFibonacciPrimes
{
    class SomeFibonacciPrimes
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to find if it's in Fibonacci      range:");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (IsFibonacci(number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is within the Fibonacci range.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is NOT within the Fibonacci range");
            }
       }




        static bool IsFibonacci(int number)
        {
            //Uses a closed form solution for the fibonacci number calculation.
            //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

            double fi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2.0; //Golden ratio
            int n = (int) Math.Floor(Math.Log(number * Math.Sqrt(5) + 0.5, fi)); //Find's the index (n) of the given number in the fibonacci sequence

            int actualFibonacciNumber = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Pow(fi, n) / Math.Sqrt(5) + 0.5); //Finds the actual number corresponding to given index (n)

            return actualFibonacciNumber == number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In here "if (IsFibonacci(number))" what is this "IsFibonacci"? I didn't quiet get it

Comment: Try to pay attention to whole code. I made it somehow readable enough :)